# How do I aggregate on over the subset and return one value?

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregation

I have a dataset like below:

```
id tag x y z
1  "A" 1 2 3
2  "B" 0 2 4
3  "A" 0 0 1
4  "B" 1 3 4
```

I have a function `agg`, which takes subsets grouped by `tag`, that is, the parameter is:

```
id tag x y z
1  "A" 1 2 3
3  "A" 0 0 1
```

Let's say `agg` is a simple sum over all `x` `y` `z` in the subset, so giving a result of `7`, for subset with `tag=="A"`.

So what i want is an end result like:

```
"A" 7
"B" 14
...
```

I can list all values of `tag` and loop them to get the individual subset then feed it to the function. Is there a better way? I am guessing there must be some library does this nicely..

Edit: I have changed the question to give better description. Hope I made it clear this time.

I think the difficulty I have is the aggregating function takes the entire subset to produce a value, while normal aggregating functions(mean,length,etc) takes a variable from the subset.

Comment: Could you please give a reproducible example ?

Comment: There are multiple ways to "aggregate" data as you mention, but what kind of aggregation are you looking for? A sum? A mean? The number of entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to reshape using reshape2. . .

```
library(reshape2)
df <- read.table(
  header=TRUE, text='
id tag x y z
1  "A" 1 2 3
2  "B" 0 2 4
3  "A" 0 0 1
4  "B" 1 3 4
')
df[,1]<- NULL
df2<- melt(df, id="tag")
dcast(df2, tag~., sum)

#  tag NA
#1   A  7
#2   B 14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ds <- read.table(text='id tag x y z
 1  "A" 1 2 3
 2  "B" 0 2 4
 3  "A" 0 0 1
 4  "B" 1 3 4', header=TRUE)

lapply(split(ds[c('x','y','z')], ds$tag), sum)
$A
[1] 7

$B
[1] 14
```